# Kubernetes Ingress (GCE) causes default service selectors to stop working

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to setup a blue/green deployment environment for an application. So far everything has worked fairly well using this spec (simplified to the relevant parts): https://gist.github.com/haleyrc/3c648087ceeb2aa762b7a7b0efefaa3a.

The deployment process involves updating the image for the not-in-use deployment, waiting for the rollout to complete, and then changing the color selector for the service. This all works as intended which I verified by initially setting the service up as a `LoadBalancer` and repeatedly curling the external IP which just returned the pod name.

If I go through the `Ingress`, however, everything appears to work when initially setup, but as soon as the deployment occurs, I start getting responses from both blue and green pods. If I delete the not-in-use deployments pods and let them come back up, everything works again  until the next deployment.

I have even run the service as a `LoadBalancer` at the same time as the `Ingress` was running and `curl`ed both simultaneously. The responses from the `Service` were only from the in-use deployment, while the responses from the `Ingress` were a mix of in-use and not-in-use.

There is no caching enabled on my backend service and no CDN in place. What's more, doing a `kubectl describe ingress backend-ingress` shows the correct service backend and the IPs of the correct pods.

Is there something simple I'm missing that could cause responses from pods outside of the selected group but *only* when passed through a GCE Ingress?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior using your yaml file with slight modification. I basically, added a config map since I don't have access to use the image in your configure and got response I am green or I am blue response response. Hence, can you check your config file to make sure that attributes were properly defined?